# Add ticks to ggplot after zooming with coord_cartesian

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem adding ticks to the y-axis of a plot after 'zooming'. I use `coord_cartesian` for zooming because scale_y_continuous removes some of my data points and recalculates the values for the boxplots. However, `scale_y_continuous` gives me the opportunity to specify ticks using e.g.    `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,50), breaks = seq(0,50, by=5))`. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work for `coord_cartesian`. Does anyone know How can I specify ticks in combination with `coord_cartesian`?

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rep(c("X1","X2","X3","X4"),50),
                  y = rep(c("Y1","Y2","Y3","Y4","Y5"),40),
                  z = sample(1:200, 200))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=z, fill=y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 50))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can still use `scale_y_continuous` with `coord_cartesian`

```
+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,50, by=5))
```

[image]